# How to hide source code in C#

Tags: c#, obfuscation, windows

I am making an application for Windows, and I am almost done. How can I hide my source code?

I want to give my application to my friend, but I don't know how to hide my code and make an application like professional.

How do I replace new DLL files with old .cs files?

Comment: create an `exe` file and give

Comment: _"hide my code and make an app like pro"_ - that has nothing to do with each other.

Comment: You mean like hiding your code from getting reverse engineered?

Comment: Create a dll (dynamic link libray) and expose only the functionality you wanted and have it your friends reference onto that dll.

Comment: Just build the application and send, unless your friend knows how to disassemble the CIL code. If he does, you need an obfuscator.

Comment: obfuscator only encrypt strings not the IL itself, using this will only make it a bit harder to decode but still possible to decode.

Comment: Might be easier to only make friends with people you can trust.

Comment: You have two options. NGen your application so its native from the start... or use a non-.NET language such as C++. Obfuscation is useless... it hides only the basics and can be 100% decompiled to readable IL.

Comment: i converted all the .cs files to dll files.how can i refer them in visual studio 2012

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for I think is changing your app so your source code can't easily be found by decompiling your .exe/.dll. This process is called obfuscation. For C# Dotfuscator is a good start: http://www.preemptive.com/support/dotfuscator-support

Comment: While this answers the question... obfuscation is useless.

Comment: It is not useless, it makes it way harder for another programmer to grasp what the code means. Any program can be decompiled, but making the decompiled code hard to read gets you a long way.

Comment: There is a certain decompiler that makes it readable again. Its open source too. It reverses the XOR'd strings and symbol renaming that most obfuscators perform.

Answer (score -3):

Not beneficial to convert or change the code ; You have to create `.exe` or if you to show *design view* you can share *snapshots*.